# MongoDb connection pool issues at multi task .NET 6 application

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-6.0, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a multi task `worker` application in .NET 6. Multi task count sometimes growing about 4000 and all task are running simultaneously. My challenge is start here.

If I remove database operations, application working fine.

If I decrease task count and made connection pool about 500, also working fine. And also if I run same service as 3 instances. Everything fine again.

However, both scenario is not good for me. I need single application and observe mongodb server for operation statuses and slow queries. There is nothing about server. My issue completely related with .Net driver of MongoDb.

In my application, I have single instance for MongoDb, how explained in its documentation.

My issues are that;

1. Increasing pool size 500 or more, I get an error about `MongoWaitQueueFullException`.

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoWaitQueueFullException: The wait queue for acquiring a connection to server localhost:27017 is full.
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.ConnectionPools.ExclusiveConnectionPool.AcquireConnectionHelper.AcquireWaitQueueSlot()
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.ConnectionPools.ExclusiveConnectionPool.AcquireConnectionHelper.StartCheckingOut()
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.ConnectionPools.ExclusiveConnectionPool.AcquireConnectionHelper.AcquireConnectionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.ConnectionPools.ExclusiveConnectionPool.AcquireConnectionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.Server.GetChannelAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableWriteContext.InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableWriteContext.CreateAsync(IWriteBinding binding, Boolean retryRequested, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.BulkMixedWriteOperation.ExecuteAsync(IWriteBinding binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.ExecuteWriteOperationAsync[TResult](IWriteBinding binding, IWriteOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.ExecuteWriteOperationAsync[TResult](IClientSessionHandle session, IWriteOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.BulkWriteAsync(IClientSessionHandle session, IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSessionAsync[TResult](Func`2 funcAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.DeleteOneAsync(FilterDefinition`1 filter, DeleteOptions options, Func`3 bulkWriteAsync)
```

2. If I decreasing pool size that time, getting `TimeoutException` exception.

```
System.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting in connecting queue after 7730ms.
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.ConnectionPools.ExclusiveConnectionPool.ConnectionCreator.CreateOpenedOrReuseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.ConnectionPools.ExclusiveConnectionPool.AcquireConnectionHelper.AcquireConnectionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

How I could reach to success with more 4000 tasks at same time? Which setting missed?

Software and package informations:
MongoDB Server 6.0
.Net 6
MongoDB Driver 2.17.1

Comment: see https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/frequently_encountered_issues/

Comment: @dododo I read that and do them, also mentioned them in question. Do you think which part I'm missing?

Comment: 4. Increase waitQueueMultiple to allow more threads/tasks to block waiting for a connection. This is rarely the right solution. It is better to address the concurrency problems in your application.

Comment: `waitQueueMultiple` does not solve the problem. The software still down on load.

Comment: there is no buildin solution for your issue, you're starting creating 4000 tasks which in general means that driver starts creating 4000 connections to work with your operations if this tasks started to make operations at the same time. To make it work you should play with either: 1. number of tasks 2. running these tasks not at the same time to allow some connections be reused. 3. configuring appropriate maxConnections and waitQueueMultiple values